# NoClassDefFoundError: AmazonSNSClient in Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I got the error Class Definition not found when I try to instantiate AWSSNSClient.This code is not running in AWS Lambda its local system. 
Here is my Java code

```
   18->   AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(credentials);
        snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.));
        ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
        publishRequest.setTargetArn("");
        publishRequest.setMessage("");
        PublishResult publishResponse = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cmds</groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name></name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.379</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-flow</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.721</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I received the following error when the java code executes

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient
at com.cmds.booking.infrastructure.SNSService.publishMessage(SNSService.java:18)

Any dependency issue ? Where I have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I have examined your Java code snippet to the best of my ability and there are two issues that I've noted:

**( i )** The line below is incomplete :

```
snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.));
```

and should be changed to :

```
snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)); //US_EAST_1 can be replaced with your desired region
```

**( ii )** The following declaration are deprecated:

```
new AmazonSNSClient(credentials)
```

and

```
snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(region)));
```

Instead, AWS service clients should be created as follows :

If you are using a credential file then you can use the following :

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey,SecretAccessKey);
AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClient
                    .builder()
                    .withRegion(your_region)
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAwsCredentials))
                    .build();
```

If you are going to use InstanceProfileCredentialProvider then you can use the following :

```
AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true))
                .build();
```

More information can be found on [AWS Java developer guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-java-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/credentials.rst)

Hope this helps!